# Truncate Multivariate Polynomial to Degree

Tags: series-expansion

I am working with multivariate polynomials, e.g.

```
Expand[Normal[Series[d/Sqrt[(1 - x^2 + y^2)], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]]]
```

which for this example results in

$\frac{105 x^4 y^4}{64}-\frac{15 x^4 y^2}{16}+\frac{3 x^4}{8}+\frac{15 x^2 y^4}{16}-\frac{3
   x^2 y^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3 y^4}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+1$

**How can truncate the polynomial to a "combined degree" $d\leq i+j, x^iy^j$?**

Expected result for the given example and $d=5$:

$\frac{3 x^4}{8}-\frac{3
   x^2 y^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3 y^4}{8}-\frac{y^2}{2}+1$

Comment: By modifying the answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147201/how-to-replace-large-powers-in-a-series) you might be able to get what you want.

Comment: @MiladP. the answer linked as duplicate is exactly what I wanted. I was just unable to find the answer using google or the site search because the title of the duplicate is bad.