# How to replace large powers in a series?

Tags: replacement, series-expansion, rule

How do I go about replacing terms with large powers of a variable in an arbitrary series? For instance, I would like to transform $1 + a x + b x^2 + c x^3 + d x^4 + e x^5$ to $1 + a x + b x^2$, dropping terms with $x$ to the power of 3 or higher. Preferably, I like to learn how to do this with `_` or other [functional programming](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionalProgramming.html) features of *Mathematica*.

Comment: How about `expr /. x^n_ /; n>2 -> 0`?

Comment: What happened when you checked for "series" in documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = 1 + a x + b x^2 + c x^3 + d x^4 + e x^5;

expr /. Power[x, _?(# > 2 &)] :> 0
(* or expr /. Power[x, n_ /; n > 2] :> 0 *)
```

> 1 + a x + b x^2

Notes: see [PatternTest (?)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternTest.html) and [Condition (/;)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html)

Alternatively,you can use `Series`:

```
Normal@Series[expr, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> 1 + a x + b x^2

Comment: Even though correct, I don't like the first option. I was looking for what you have as your second option. Thanks! I suggest switching the order and explaining what `?` does. In case you find it unnecessary, I'll leave this link for others to learn about `?`: [PatternTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html).

Comment: "Even though correct, I don't like the first option." - @Milad, can you explain why? The second snippet only works for explicitly expanded out polynomials, while the first can still work even if the polynomial is in factored form.

Comment: Excellent point @J.M. But that would not affect my question in hand. In the first method, rather than setting the large powers to zero, one is writing the series as another series in the Big O notation (where the large powers reside) and dropping it by expressing it in the `Normal` form. However, the second method does exactly what I was asking in the question; It actually DROPS large powers. Also, I wanted to learn about `_?test` which I didn't know existed before this asking this question.